# Why collision is not working for UR5

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using UR5 robot in Gazebo but I've noticed when there is no controller, the collision detection is not working in Gazebo 9. I'm wondering what is the problem. As you can see in the below picture, some parts penetrate others. I'm using the files in [universal robot](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot). I see the collision models are provided in `urdf` file. I'm using melodic in Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400947/why-collision-is-not-working-for-ur5/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's probably because [self_collide](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.9&elem=link#link_self_collide) is off by default for links. As the description reads, it will not collide with links of the same model.

This can be very desirable if you have (for instance) a car, where you have set the chassis as a simple square representation. That would mean half of the wheels technically collide with the chassis. Since a square would be used to simplify computations (by a significant amount) it's desirable to use.

In your case, I can imagine you want to have `self_collide` turned on. However, it's also good to check how the collisions look and if they don't have a little overlap by default.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-20**:
how to turn it on?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
By adding the tag

```
<gazebo reference="**link_name**">
     <self_collide>true</self_collide>
</gazebo>
```

Note that links that share a joint will never collide with one another. So parents will never collide with children or the other way around.